# Position: sticky (firefox) on a <table> element

Tags: css, position, sticky

The new value of position is very confusing to me.. a lot of search result give javascript/jQuery (JavaScript-framework) solutions.

In the example in bottom i have a `table` with a `thead` and `tbody`.

No matter what i cannot achieve the desire result.
Desire result is thead to be sticky to the table. sticky means when not in view the element is some kind of `position:fixed` fixed means it sticks to your screen.  *What i did try:*

- `display: inline/block/inline-block;`
- th element `position:sticky` (th element is an element inside a tr witch is inside a thead element)
- mix of `display:inline/block` etc; (values of property display)

I just cannot find how to achieve this sticky in firefox (supported)

Any solutions ??

(as `position:sticky` still an experimental API and should not be used in production site http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position )

```css
table {
  background-color: rgba(241, 31, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100%;
}
thead {
  background-color: rgba(241, 0, 241, 0.3);
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
}
th {} tbody td:nth-child(2) {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You've told us everything you've tried, said that none of them gave you the desired result, but... you haven't actually told us what you want.

Comment: @Gaurav Aggarwal: Do not repost comments after they are deleted by a moderator.

Comment: So, based on the title, you just want to sticky your table element, am I right? If so, that should work fine, a table is no different than any other block-level element in that respect. But your code says you are applying position sticky to the thead and not the entire table. So which one is it? And who promised what exactly?

Comment: While @BoltClock is a moderator he also happens to be an expert in CSS :)  He's trying to help you improve your question via comments to clarify what your question really is and for you to get an answer - no need to be worried about that!

Comment: Thank you Jon, i noticed he was is a moderator. It does not feel that way when he closed my question. But thanks for the kind words.

Comment: firefox seems not to allow yet to 'stick' table elements, a workaround would be to set table as block, then thead, tbody, tfoot to display:table; so one of them can be sticked. unfortunately this breaks the table-layout and split table into few tables .. :(  **you also need to set coordonates where sticky comes in action**http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/reoExq . not the best :(

Comment: @GCyrillus thank you so much!!! BoltBlock and another user keep thrashing this question. so correct me if i'm wrong... caniuse.com etc are wrogn when they say position:sticky is live

Comment: @BoltClock and still this question is relevant from the start still it is on hold..

Comment: caniuse might be not up to date, every updates of browsers comes with differences :) bugs fixed, new bugs, new features, less features ...

Comment: @Phil Andelhofs: Looks better now, thanks. I have already dealt with the other user.

Comment: @GCyrillus you have a link of mozzila where table not supported yet ?

Comment: @GCyrillus: The position property generally doesn't work very well with internal table boxes - just about any value really will mess with table layout. So, no surprises there...

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs nop, it is just observation, since i know sticky works fine in ff

Comment: @BoltClock right, ff & table had unexpected behaviors with table/position

Comment: @GCyrillus your solution works with multiple table element on screen. But what i do not understand, i understand it triggers.. top:0px; is this generally need to trigger the sticky ?

Comment: yes it is to tell where on scrolling , it should remain still. so it can move a bit , but at a point stay still

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firefox **seems** not to allow yet 'sticky' on table childs elements.

a workaround would be to set `table` as `block`, then `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot` to `display:table;` so one of them can be sticked.

unfortunately this breaks the table-layout and split table into few tables .. :(

you also need to set coordonates where sticky comes in action  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/reoExq . not the best :(

CSS base would be like:

```
table {
  display: block;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;  /* trigger sticky when reaches coordonates */
}

thead, tbody, tfoot {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
table {
  background-color: rgba(241, 31, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1em;
  position: static;
  display: block;
}
thead {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(241, 0, 241, 0.3);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  /* trigger sticky when reaches coordonates */
}
tbody {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
th {} tbody td:nth-child(2) {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Another method is to use css3 to translate the header cells. This method does require javascript and will work in all modern browsers, but because it translates the table cell, the border does not get included for some reason ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bfocjv9s/))

Also, this css is necessary to include a background color on the translated cells

```
thead th,
caption {
  background: #fff;
}
```

jQuery

```
var $win = $(window),
  $table = $('table'),
  $thead = $table.children('thead'),
  $tfoot = $table.children('tfoot'),
  $caption = $table.children('caption'),
  $cells = $thead.children().children().add($caption);

$win.on('scroll', function() {
  var bottom = $table.position().top +
        $table.height() -
        $thead.height() -
        ($tfoot.height() || 0),
    delta = $win.scrollTop() -
        $thead.offset().top +
        $caption.outerHeight(),
    // include border thickness (minus 2)
    vertPos = (delta < 0 || delta > bottom ? 0 : delta - 2);
  $cells.css("transform", "translate(0px," + vertPos + "px)");
});
```

Comment: transform and thead cell bg & borders seems buggy indeed., background-clip can help, box-shadow can reinforce it : test  http://jsfiddle.net/bfocjv9s/8/

Comment: This javascript code snippet suits particularly firefox-browser for sticky header columns. Firefox quirky mode = on?

Answer (score 1):

**Update Q1 2018**

`position: sticky` has now landed in stable Firefox 59. [The fiddle linked below](https://jsfiddle.net/zoctn6hd/) now works unchanged in Firefox as well.

---

I know you specifically asked for Firefox compatibility of `position: sticky`, but unfortunately its styling effect in Firefox is not defined on inner table elements:

> *Quoting from [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)*
>
> The effect of position:relative on table-*-group, table-row, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.
>
> **The effect of ‘position: sticky’ on table elements is the same as for ‘position: relative’.**

That being said, `position: sticky` is about to land in Chrome Stable channel (it is in Canary at the time of writing and [there's a developer.google.com blog post about it](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/position-sticky)). Their implementation does work fine on `thead`, solving my own long-standing problem of sticky theads as all other solutions fail when you need to resize the table/cell widths.

[I've created a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zoctn6hd/) to test the sticky positioning. On all channels of Firefox, this has no effect.

My hope is that `position: sticky` now gains tractions due to the more complete implementation in Chrome, it will stir discussions again on the lacking inner table support of `sticky`.

There's also a bug report on Firefox' Bugzilla:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=975644

Comment: In the specification no word about treating sticky like relative for table elements.