# How to keep the header fixed when scrolling through data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two tables, first one serves as a search functionality utilizing datepicker, and the second holds the `thead` and `tbody` which holds the actual header and rows for my data. I tried following http://jsfiddle.net/wLcjh/255/

```
var tableOffset = $("#table-1").offset().top;
var $header = $("#table-1 > thead");
var $fixedHeader = $("#header-fixed").append($header.clone());
console.log(tableOffset);
console.log($header);
console.log($fixedHeader);
console.log($fixedHeader.is(":hidden"));

$(window).bind("scroll", function () {
    var offset = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (offset >= tableOffset && $fixedHeader.is(":hidden")) {
        $fixedHeader.show();

        $.each($header.find('#tr1 > th'), function (ind, val) {
            var original_width = $(val).width();
            $($fixedHeader.find('#tr1 > th')[ind]).width(original_width);
        });
    }

});
```

However, it had no effect on my page whatsoever. Is it even possible to accomplish?

Comment: You could try using the datatables plugin https://datatables.net/, https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/

Comment: The standard way to do this is to put the header in a separate table which is fixed and let the data table scroll behind it with overflow hidden.

Comment: Your Fiddle seems to be working...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette sorry i wasn't clear, this was the example i wwas going off of, my actual code isn't as simple, theres a lot more divs surrounding the actual table.

Comment: @nurdyguy could you expand a little more, where would i put the overflow on? would that be for the thead or the tbody? and by fixed, you mean set position to fixed for the header table? Thank you for the help nonetheless

Answer (score 2):

How about doing this with plain CSS using [postion:sticky](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/)?

```css
body { height: 1000px; }
thead tr th{
    background: white;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
```

```html
<table id="table-1">
    <thead id="header-fixed">
        <tr>
            <th >Col1</th>
            <th >Col2</th>
            <th >Col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>info000000</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>infolllllllllllll</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info00000000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you. i've never used or seen that before. thank you for that! Saved me so much stressful time :)

Comment: @goldenBoy OK!  It's  a good habit to mark as answer if it helped you :)

Comment: it works on chrome.. but still no support on firefox sadly. This is why i haven't marked as answered yet. Seems that this has been a persistent issues for others around with position: sticky

Comment: @goldenBoy fair enough . I'm running on the Firefox beta channel here  , if there is any consolation  the issue you mentioned is fixed in FF59+. 
If you're looking to support older versions of firefox maybe you could try some workarounds https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071535/position-sticky-firefox-on-a-table-element

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `position: fixed;` CSS on header container to keep position fix.

Plese check below code::

```
.header-container-fixed {
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```