# How to freeze first column and first row header and others make scrollable reactjs table

Tags: css, reactjs, react-table

i have created a Dynamic table(table creation happens based on the input data, rows and columns can be changes based on data) using react js and want to freeze the first header row and header column. **The first header row is freeze using the below CSS pass(when scrolling first-row header is freeze).but i have no idea to freeze the first column header.**

[image]

```
Table thead {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import { useTable } from "react-table";
import { colors, headers, gridData } from "./util";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function App() {
  const weeksCount=11
  const Data=[ [3, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 3, 0],
  [2, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 2, 0],
  [1, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 1, 0],
  ['-', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, 0],
  ['-', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, 0],
  [11, 3, 4, '', '', '', 4, 7],
  [8, 6, 1, '', '', 1, 7],
  [1, '', '', '', 1, 0],
  ['-', '', '', 0, 0],
  ['-', '', 0, 0],
  ['-', 0, 0]];


  return (
          <div>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Week</th>
                {new Array(weeksCount)?.fill(null)?.map((_, i) => {
                  return (
                    <th>
                      <div>{i + 1}</div>
                    </th>
                  );
                })}
                <th>Net Win</th>
                <th>Net Lose</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {Data?.slice(0, weeksCount)?.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <tr>
                    <th>{index + 1}</th>

                    {[...Array(Data[0].length - item.length)]?.map(
                      () => {
                        return <td />;
                      },
                    )}
                    {item?.map((itm) => {
                      return <td>{itm}</td>;
                    })}
                  </tr>
                );
              })}

              {Data?.slice(weeksCount)?.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <tr>
                    <th />
                    {[...Array(Data[0].length - item.length)]?.map(
                      (item) => {
                        return <td />;
                      },
                    )}
                    {item?.map((itm) => {
                      return <td>{itm}</td>;
                    })}
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
          );



}
```

Comment: Can you create a snippet in your question that we could use as a starting point?

Comment: I have added please have a look.

Comment: Adam in order to work on this I would need to manually set up a React project. However, as you correctly identified, this should be a CSS-based issue. So, if you could create a snippet that runs inside this page (using the `<>` button when you edit your question) that actually runs and reproduces the issue, that would help. It's not a problem if it's not a React code, it's okay if you do it with the HTML/Javascript/CSS it generates. If it's too troublesome to do that, then you can create online React fiddles. So, I kindly ask you to build a small example where we can look into.

Comment: I think that CSS rules using the `:first-child` pseudo-selector will be the solution. But I will need an example created by you in order to try this idea and build a proof-of-concept for you.

Comment: Or, another approach to solve this is to have two `table` tags, the second nested into the first

Comment: If you are looking for sticky row headers and sticky column headers then this will probably do what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63531126/sticky-table-header-inside-overflow-x-div-with-100-width/73936569#73936569

Comment: @petern0691 yes it is so close, but when i add `tr:nth-of-type(1) {
    position: sticky;
    top: 5px;
    background: cyan;
}`,it makes 2nd row freeze.not the first one. Any idea?

Comment: I am on a mobile so it is difficult.  Add to what?  Note that example I gave does not use 'thead', so prehaps check which 'tr' you are actually selecting?